# CodeIgniter - ActiveRecord order_by() being applied to all queries not just the one I want

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Probably quite a simple one, but I'm not having any luck in the docs or searches.

I'm trying to add an order by clause to just one of my ActiveRecord queries as follows:

```
$result = $this->db->get('mytable');
$this->db->order_by('age', 'ASC');
```

It works, however I get errors because the order by clause is being applied to all my other queries and I get errors because my age column is not present in all tables.

So how do it limit $this->db->order_by('age', 'ASC') to just that one specific query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have `$this->db->order_by();` before `$result = $this->db->get('mytable');`

Comment: Knew it would be an easy one. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It should be in this format

```
$this->db->where("tablename.column", $task_id);
$this->db->order_by('tablename.column', 'ASC'); // or 'DESC'
$this->db->from('table');
```